# How would I illustrate a class holding a reference to itself, in a UML diagram?

Tags: class, reference, uml

I would like to know how to include in a class a list of references to itself, in a UML diagram.

For example: A model consists of many components.  A component can hold a list of references to its child components.

How would I illustrate this in a UML diagram?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UML does not forbid a class to have an association to its self.
Your class would show like this in a class diagram:

[image: Class diagram]